# JS caching issue with JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

I've been getting duplicated values in my database from what I believe is from my call to my JS file. I need some verification, that the way I'm generating a new JS version number is right.

```
Integer verCount = 0;


<script src="include/test.js?version=<%=verCount++ %>"></script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: *"I've been getting duplicated values in my database"* How does referencing a JS file add dupes to a DB?

Comment: From what I tested, the JS file in the cache is been called twice, when a user come back or reloads the same page.

Comment: because the file is the same each time unless you update the integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="include/test.js?version=<%= (new Date()).getTime() %>"></script>
```

A timestamp should be unique each time don't worry about keeping a count.  This will cause the js file to be reloaded each time.